# Не могу понять, где ошибка и почему он карты не инициализируются на сайте

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Ни при каких условиях, пробовал уже подключать и 3 версии ключ и обычный, всё равно ошибки выдаются, что не распознает код 3 версии,прикладываю html\js код и ошибки. Часть кода customization убрана, чтобы место не занимать

```js
let center = [59.68249328771387, 80.28810420751564];

function init() {
    let map = new ymaps3.Map('map-test', {
        center: center,
        zoom: 3,
    });
    let main = new ymaps3.Placemark([55.796238068961486, 37.76556099999989], {
        balloonContent: `

        <div class="balloon">
            <div class="balloon__address">Главный офис</div>
                <div class="main_balloon"> 
                    <p>105037, г Москва, проезд Измайловский, д. 5А, пом. 34H</p>
                </div>
                <div class="balloon__contacts">
                    <a href="tel:+74955104944">+7 (495) 510‑49-44</a>
                    <a href="mailto:info@sdmopt.com">info@sdmopt.com</a>
            </div>
            <button class="balloon_button_how">Как добраться?</button>
        </div>

`
    }, {
        iconLayout: 'default#image',
        iconImageHref: 'https://static.tildacdn.com/tild3930-3839-4532-b936-643761656462/marker.svg',
        iconImageSize: [42, 42],
        iconImageOffset: [0, -0]
    });
    let warehouse = new ymaps3.Placemark([55.82353006891234, 37.78104749999992], {
        balloonContent: `

        <div class="balloon">
            <div class="balloon__address">Складкской комплекс</div>
                <div class="main_balloon"> 
                    <p>г. Москва, 107497, ул. Иркутская д.17, стр. 8</p>
                </div>
                <div class="balloon__contacts">
                    <a href="tel:+74955104944">+7 (495) 510‑49-44</a>
                    <a href="tel:+74956603351">+7 (495) 660‑33-51</a>
                    <a href="mailto:info@sdmopt.com">info@sdmopt.com</a>
            </div>
            <button class="balloon_button_how">Как добраться?</button>
        </div>

`
    }, {
        iconLayout: 'default#image',
        iconImageHref: 'https://static.tildacdn.com/tild3930-3839-4532-b936-643761656462/marker.svg',
        iconImageSize: [32, 32],
        iconImageOffset: [0, -0]
    });
    let spb = new ymaps3.Placemark([59.88791609656807, 30.325855173610595], {
        balloonContent: `

        <div class="balloon">
            <div class="balloon__address">Санкт-Петербург</div>
                <div class="main_balloon"> 
                    <p>196084, ул. Коли Томчака д.20Б лит. В</p>
                </div>
                <div class="balloon__contacts">
                    <a href="tel:+78123870671">+7 (812) 387-06-71</a>
                    <a href="mailto:schank@mail.ru">schank@mail.ru</a>
            </div>
            <button class="balloon_button_how">Как добраться?</button>
        </div>

`
    }, {
        iconLayout: 'default#image',
        iconImageHref: 'https://static.tildacdn.com/tild3930-3839-4532-b936-643761656462/marker.svg',
        iconImageSize: [24, 24],
        iconImageOffset: [0, -0]
    });
    let kazan = new ymaps3.Placemark([55.74847256898776, 49.1120105], {
        balloonContent: `

        <div class="balloon">
            <div class="balloon__address">Казань</div>
                <div class="main_balloon"> 
                    <p>ООО “КОБРА-КАЗАНЬ”.</p>
                    <p>г.Казань, ул. Турбинная, 7</p>
                </div>
                <div class="balloon__contacts">
                    <a href="tel:+78432586266">+7 (843) 258 62 66</a>
                    <a href="tel:+79872667244">+7 (987) 266 72 44</a>
                    <a href="tel:+79274325274">+7 (927) 432 52 74</a>
                    <a href="mailto:cobra-kazan@yandex.ru">cobra-kazan@yandex.ru</a>
            </div>
            <button class="balloon_button_how">Как добраться?</button>
        </div>

`
    }, {
        iconLayout: 'default#image',
        iconImageHref: 'https://static.tildacdn.com/tild3930-3839-4532-b936-643761656462/marker.svg',
        iconImageSize: [24, 24],
        iconImageOffset: [0, -0]
    });
    let krasnodar = new ymaps3.Placemark([45.01330007458955, 38.995740499999954], {
        balloonContent: `

        <div class="balloon">
            <div class="balloon__address">Краснодар</div>
                <div class="main_balloon"> 
                    <p>350001, ул. Вишняковой, 5/2</p>
                </div>
                <div class="balloon__contacts">
                    <a href="tel:+78612990505">+7 (861) 299-05-05</a>
                    <a href="mailto:89180989898@mail.ru">89180989898@mail.ru</a>
            </div>
            <button class="balloon_button_how">Как добраться?</button>
        </div>

`
    }, {
        iconLayout: 'default#image',
        iconImageHref: 'https://static.tildacdn.com/tild3930-3839-4532-b936-643761656462/marker.svg',
        iconImageSize: [24, 24],
        iconImageOffset: [0, -0]
    });
    let ussuruisk = new ymaps3.Placemark([43.792093074582596, 131.97923299999994], {
        balloonContent: `

        <div class="balloon">
            <div class="balloon__address">Уссурийск</div>
                <div class="main_balloon"> 
                    <p>Олеся Кожемякина</p>
                    <p>Менеджер по продажам ООО «СДМ»</p>
                </div>
                <div class="balloon__contacts">
                    <a href="tel:+79146815702">+7(914) 681-57-02</a>
                    <a href="mailto:ussursdm@mail.ru">ussursdm@mail.ru</a>
            </div>
            <button class="balloon_button_how">Как добраться?</button>
        </div>

`
    }, {
        iconLayout: 'default#image',
        iconImageHref: 'https://static.tildacdn.com/tild3930-3839-4532-b936-643761656462/marker.svg',
        iconImageSize: [24, 24],
        iconImageOffset: [0, -0]
    });

    map.controls.remove('geolocationControl'); // удаляем геолокацию
    map.controls.remove('trafficControl'); // удаляем контроль трафика
    map.controls.remove('searchControl'); // удаляем поиск
    map.controls.remove('typeSelector'); // удаляем тип
    map.controls.remove('fullscreenControl'); // удаляем кнопку перехода в полноэкранный режим
    map.controls.remove('rulerControl'); // удаляем контрол правил
    map.behaviors.disable(['scrollZoom']); // отключаем скролл карты (опционально)

    map.geoObjects.add(main);
    map.geoObjects.add(warehouse);
    map.geoObjects.add(spb);
    map.geoObjects.add(kazan);
    map.geoObjects.add(krasnodar);
    map.geoObjects.add(ussuruisk);
}


ymaps3.ready(init);

map.addChild(new YMapDefaultSchemeLayer({
    customization: 
}));
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="map-test" class="map"></div>
    <script src="https://api-maps.yandex.ru/v3/?apikey=***мойапиключ***&lang=ru_RU"></script>
    </script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы используете классы для JS API 2.1, но подключаете их с помощью ymaps3 — пространства имён для третьей версии. Подключение API в HTML-коде также должно быть для используемой в проекте версии, шаблоны подключения можно взять из раздела Документации Быстрый старт для [JS API 2.1](https://yandex.ru/dev/jsapi-v2-1/doc/ru/#result_map) и для [JS API 3.0](https://yandex.ru/dev/jsapi30/doc/ru/quickstart#polnyj-tekst-primera).

Присылаю исправленный [пример](https://jsbin.com/qokulaw/edit?html,js,output), карта инициализируется и метки отображаются на карте.